# $\cos 2\pi n\theta> 1-\varepsilon$ infinitely often?

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, divergent-series

Suppose $\theta >0$ is irrational. Is it true that for $n\in\mathbb N$
$$ \cos 2\pi n\theta > 1-\varepsilon \tag{1} $$
holds infinitely often?

The question is inspired by a series candidate (posted by another user) whose terms are of the form $(\exp(i2\pi n\theta)-1)^{-1}$. My intuition says the terms are norm-wise large infinitely often (for irrational $\theta$) so the series diverges. But if anything, I'm just practicing technique.

For divergence purposes, it's sufficient that there is some $\varepsilon_0$ for which (1) holds i.o. For example, can we make $\cos 2\pi n\theta > 0.5$ i.o?  It holds that $\cos x >0.5$ if $x \in \left ( -\pi/3 + 2\pi k, \pi/3 + 2\pi k \right )$ for some $k\in \mathbb N$ ($x<0$ not relevant for now). With that in mind I get the inequalities
$$ 6k-1 < 6n\theta < 6k+1 $$
and I'm stuck. Does this hold infinitely often? More specifically, does there exist a subsequence $m_n$ such that for every $n$ there exists $k_n$ satisfying
$$ 6k_n -1< 6m_n\theta < 6k_n+1? $$

I vaguely remember problems of this sort, but I can't recall relevant keywords to find such problems.

Comment: Yes, it boils down to if $w$ is irrational, and $b$ is non-zero rational (or alternatively $w,b$ are non-zero and $\frac wb$ is irrational) then for any $\epsilon > 0$ there are integers $n,m$ so that $0< nw -mb < \epsilon$.  This is a consequence of the archemedian property. It's clear there are infinitely many solutions as if we can find $n,m$ so that $0<nw-mb< \epsilon$ then we can find $n_1,m_1$ so that $n_1w-m_1b < nw-mb$.

Comment: Yes. This is a famous application of the pigeonhole principle: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle#Uses_and_applications

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $\theta$ is irrational then $ n\theta$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$. Hence $2\pi n\theta$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,2\pi]$ so, since $\cos $ is continuous the sequence is dense on $[-1,1]$.
In particular, it gets as close to $1$ as possible.

Comment: Ah you mean $n\theta - \lfloor n\theta \rfloor$ is uniform on $[0,1]$. Neat, thanks!