# For any $\epsilon>0$, there exists arbitrarily large $x$ with $\cos( x^2)>1-\epsilon$ and $\cos[ (x+1)^2]<-1+\epsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, ergodic-theory, equidistribution

> For any $\epsilon>0$, there exists arbitrarily large $x$ with $\cos (x^2)>1-\epsilon$ and $\cos [(x+1)^2]<-1+\epsilon$.

This is an exercise in "Uniform Distribution of Sequences" by Kuipers, Niederreiter.

If I remember correctly, I may have been given a hint that we need to use the fact that the sequence $\left\{\frac {n^2}{2\pi}\right\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is uniformly distributed modulo $1$ (although I'm not sure whether this was indeed the hint), but I can't figure out how to use that.

Also, since this question *sounds like* a question from Calc I, is there a way to solve this using only properties of the cosine function without using results from Uniform Distribution of sequences?

Note: AlvinL posted [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4499314/sequence-of-irrationals-within-certain-sequence-of-bounds-infinitely-often) which does look like the first half of this question, but we should note that this question asks to prove that there are arbitrarily large $x$ which simultaneously satisfy the two given conditions.

Comment: For $\epsilon=0$ it's impossible for $\cos(x+1)^2<-1+\epsilon$ because the left hand side is nonnegative.

Comment: Is $\cos(x+1)^2$ meant to meant $[\cos(x+1)]^2$ or $\cos[(x+1)^2]$?

Comment: @mordecaiiwazuki of course, but the question says $\epsilon>0$

Comment: @QC_QAOA I would say, it means $\cos[(x+1)^2]$

Comment: I recently asked basically the first half of this question [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4499314/sequence-of-irrationals-within-certain-sequence-of-bounds-infinitely-often)

Comment: @SayanDutta taking $\epsilon=0$ isn't the problem, you could have also taken $\epsilon=0.5$ and have the same issue - the problem was where you put the square.

Comment: @AlvinL thanks for the link, but please note that the question I posted asks to prove that there are arbitrarily large $x$ which simultaneously satisfy the two given conditions

Comment: It would be sufficient to show that the sequence $\alpha_n:=\frac{1}{2}(\cos(n^2)+\cos((n+1)^2)),\,n\in\Bbb N$ is equidistributed in $[0,1]$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x_k=k\sqrt{2\pi}$ for $k\in\mathbb N$, then $\cos(x_k^2) =1$ and $$\cos[(x_k+1) ^2]=\cos(2k^2\pi+2k\sqrt{2\pi}+1) =\cos(2k\sqrt{2\pi}+1).$$

Now, we need [AlvinL's link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4499314/sequence-of-irrationals-within-certain-sequence-of-bounds-infinitely-often). We have $2\sqrt{2\pi}/(2\pi) $ is irrational. Hence, the fractional part of $( 2k\sqrt{2\pi})/(2\pi)$ is uniformly distributed on $[0, 1]$. Then the fractional part of $( 2k\sqrt{2\pi} +1)/(2\pi)$ is uniformly distributed on $[0, 1]$.

So $(2k\sqrt{2\pi} +1\bmod 2\pi)$ is uniformly distributed in $[0,2\pi]$, which means $\cos( 2k\sqrt{2\pi} +1)$ is dense in $[-1, 1]$. Especially, there is a $k$ with $\cos( 2k\sqrt{2\pi} +1) <-1+\epsilon$.

Comment: Thanks, got it (+1)!

Comment: @SayanDutta you can accept an answer (click the checkmark) to denote that your question was answered and that you find it acceptable.